# If $G$ is a graph of order $n \ge 3$ such that $\deg v \ge n/2$ for each vertex of $G$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory

In “The Fascinating World of Graph Theory” is the theorem listed above and I am having trouble understanding one of the claims.

Their proof starts as follows:

> Suppose that $P=(v_1, v_2,…,v_k)$ is a path of greatest length in $G$. Then $k \le n$. Since $P$ is a longest path in $G$, every vertex adjacent to $v_1$ must be on $P$, as is every vertex adjacent to $v_k$.

This last sentence seems to need more explanation to me - why do all of the vertices adjacent to say $v_1$ need to be on the path? A path can’t repeat vertices so how are we guaranteed that all of these vertices are on $P$?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

If $v_1$ is adjacent to a vertex $w \notin \{v_2, v_3, \dots, v_k\}$, then $P' = (w, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k)$ is a longer path than $P$. The same thing happens if $v_k$ is adjacent to a vertex not on the path.

Either of these contradicts the assumption that $P$ is a longest path in $G$.